Supabase and nextjs - Seeing client side cookies with serverside auth
I set up a next project with supabase, using below guidelines for server side cookies.
However, I'm still seeing client side cookies when logged in. Isn't this a xss vulnerability and isn't it the whole point of server side auth to not rely on client side cookies?
https://supabase.com/docs/guides/auth/quickstarts/nextjs
https://supabase.com/docs/guides/auth/server-side/nextjs
Another way of asking would be: why doesn't Supabase use HttpOnly for their server side cookies?

Are you merely talking about the HttpOnly flag, or - what exactly?

@CBroe technically, yes, but this is abstracted away in the supabase libraries. In the browser, I can just call document.cookie and I'll get an (auth-related) cookie. So another way of framing this is "why doesn't supabase use HttpOnly for their server side cookies?"

Probably related to https://supabase.com/docs/guides/auth/sessions#can-i-use-http-only-cookies-to-store-the-access-and-refresh-tokens, although I am not sure I completely understand their reasoning there. Not sure what client-side JS would need access to those values for, if not in the context of an HTTP request.
